# Injecting service for another service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have few levels of services calling each other, i.e. a `ComponentService` that uses a `DataService` that uses an `ErrorService`.

Now, one of the components services, needs to specify that the `ErrorService` instance used by the `DataService` should be of e.g. `SpecialErrorService` type. - and it does not use the `ErrorService` or the `SpecialErrorService` directly.

How can I instruct the data service to inject the correct `ErrorService` type when instantiating? (Note that I want this behavour only for a specific `ComponentService`, not as a general case)

```js
@Injectable()
export class SpecialComponentService {
  constructor(private _dataService: DataService){}

  log() {
     //expecting this to log: I'm a special error service
     this._dataService.log();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class RegularComponentService {
  constructor(private _dataService: DataService){}

  log() {
     //expecting this to log: I'm a regularerror service
     this._dataService.log();
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  constructor(private _errorService: ErrorService){}

  log() {
     this._errorService.log();
  }
}


@Injectable()
export class ErrorService {
  log(){
    console.log("I'm a regular error service");
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class SpecialErrorService extends ErrorService {
  log(){
    console.log("I'm a special error service");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Comment: Why don't just just make the constructor parameter of type `ConsoleErrorService`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - I use the exact same DataService both for regular and special behaviour.

Comment: You can do it if `SpecialDataService` and `RegularDataService` are provided in different components or at least one is provided in a lazy loaded module where a different provider for the `DataService` is registered. Otherwise I don't see a way to do this using DI configuration.

Comment: The data service is quite a large piece of code that I would not like to duplicate - I'm trying to get this with the current DI setup.

Answer (score 0):

When providing the service you can substitute it by a special service.
For example if you use it within a component, you can provide it like this:

{ provide: ErrorService, useClass: SpecialErrorService }

PS: I wanted to post this as comment but I'm not allowed to. Says I need a 50 reputation...